# Given a probability density function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 100 \\ \frac{a}{x^2} & x \geq 100 \end{cases}$. Probability distribution function?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Given a probability density function:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 100 \\ \\ \frac{a}{x^2} & x \geq 100 \end{cases} $$

What is the probability distribution function F(x)?

- We know that: $F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}f(x)dx$
- When $x < 100$:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  F(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^{y}0dx \\\\
       &= 0 \Biggr|_{-\infty}^{y} \\\\
       &= 0
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$
- When $x \geq 100$:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  F(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^{100}0dx + \int_{100}^{y}\frac{a}{x^2}dx \\\\
       &= 0 \Biggr|_{-\infty}^{100} + \left( -\frac{a}{x} \right) \Biggr|_{100}^{y} \\\\
       &= -\frac{a}{y} + \frac{a}{100} \\\\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$
- So:
  $$ F(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y < 100 \\ \\ -\frac{a}{y} + \frac{a}{100} & y \geq 100 \end{cases}$$

When $x >= 100$, $F(x)$ should be equal to 1 but it contains $a$.

I think that $F(x) = 1$ and $a = 100$ but do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first find $a$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx=1$. This gives $\frac a {100}=1$ or $a=100$.

[$1= \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx=0+\int_{100}^{\infty} \frac a {x^{2}}dx=\frac a {100}$. Hence, $a=100$].

Once you have  this value of $a$ your computation of $F(y)$ is correct.

Comment: I try to solve $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx = 1$ but it still contains $a$ like I did. Could you show me how to solve please?

Comment: I have edited. $F(y) <1$ for $y \geq 100$ and $F(y) \to 1$ as $ y \to \infty$. @null

Answer (score 0):

You know $\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} F(y) =1$ since this is a probability distribution on the real numbers

You have $\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \left(-\frac{a}{y} + \frac{a}{100}\right) = \frac{a}{100} $

So you need $\frac{a}{100} =1 $ and thus $a=100$, and that is a proof.